# Password is getting cached somewhere, need to clear it

Tags: swift

I am working on an app that accesses a REST API Webservice.  Everything is working great, except I recently started working on the the ability to logout and switch users and I've run into a strange situation.  If I log out, and then click login again without entering the password it's working.  I've even debugged the code and see that the password is blank, but the authentication is still working.  Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import LocalAuthentication

var userName = String()
var password = String()
var server = String()
var port = String()
var myUser = User()
var myExtensions = [ExtensionListItem]()
var myDevices = [Device]()

class LoginViewController: UIViewController, NSURLSessionDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

let authContext: LAContext = LAContext()

var logOutUser = Bool()

@IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
@IBOutlet weak var serverNameField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var usernameField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var loginEnable: UIButton!
var userPasswordString = NSString()
let userRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
var userSession = NSURLSession()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(logoff), name: "logoff", object: nil)
    if logOutUser {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue("", forKey: "password")
        NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().removeAllCachedResponses()
        userPasswordString = NSString()
    }
    //Determine if the user has a stored Username and populate the usernameField if possible
    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("userName") != nil{
        usernameField.text = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("userName") as? String}
    //Determine if the user has a stored ServerName and populate the serverNameField if possible.
    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("serverName") != nil{
        serverNameField.text = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("serverName") as? String}
    //Determin if the user has requested to use Touch ID
    if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("useTouchID") != nil) {
        if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("useTouchID") as! Bool == true && CheckTouchIDCapable(){
            //Trigger Touch ID
            usernameField.enabled = false
            passwordField.enabled = false
            serverNameField.enabled = false
            activityIndicator.startAnimating()
            TouchIDCall()
        }
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func logoff(){
    NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().removeAllCachedResponses()
    userSession.invalidateAndCancel()
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().removeAllCachedResponses()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func loginButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(usernameField.text, forKey: "userName")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(passwordField.text, forKey: "password")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(serverNameField.text, forKey: "serverName")

    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("touchIDPreferenceSet") == nil  && CheckTouchIDCapable() {
        DisplayTouchIDQuestion("Use Touch ID?", message: "Would you like to use touch ID to login?")
    }else{
        usernameField.enabled = false
        passwordField.enabled = false
        serverNameField.enabled = false
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        CheckUser()
    }
    print("Password: \(password)")
    print("Stored Password: \(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("password"))")
    print("?? \(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("password"))")

}

func CheckUser(){


    userName = (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("userName") as? String)!
    if !logOutUser{
        password = (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("password") as? String)!
    }
    server = (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("serverName") as? String)!
    port = "8443"
    // set up the base64-encoded credentials
    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    userPasswordString = NSString(format: "%@:%@", userName, password)
    let userPasswordData = userPasswordString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let base64EncodedCredential = userPasswordData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
    let authString = "Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)"
    config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders?.removeAll()
    config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : authString]
    config.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10.0


    // create the user request
    let userUrlString = NSString(format: "https://%@:%@/webserver/user/%@", server, port, userName)
    let userUrl = NSURL(string: userUrlString as String)
    userRequest.cachePolicy = .ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
    userRequest.URL = userUrl!
    userRequest.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    userRequest.setValue("Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    userSession = NSURLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue:NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())

    //Send User Request to the server and populate labels with response.
    _ = userSession.dataTaskWithRequest(userRequest) { (data, response, error) in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

            if error?.code != nil{
                print("ERROR: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                self.DisplayAlert("Error", message: error!.localizedDescription)
            }else{
                _ = NSString (data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                let accessDenied = Bool(dataString?.rangeOfString("HTTP Status 403").location != NSNotFound)
                let authFailure = Bool(dataString?.rangeOfString("HTTP Status 401").location != NSNotFound)

                if (authFailure || accessDenied) {
                    print("\(NSDate()): Unsuccessful Password Authentication Attempt for user: \(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("userName")!)")
                    self.DisplayAlert("Access Denied", message: "Please Verify Your Credentials")
                }else{
                    print("\(NSDate()): Successful Password Authentication for user: \(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("userName")!)")
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("authenticated", sender: self)
                }
            }
        })
    }.resume()
}

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential?) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential, NSURLCredential(forTrust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}

// MARK: - Keyboard Functions

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    if textField == passwordField  && usernameField.text != "" && serverNameField.text != ""{
        loginButton(self)
    }
    return true
}

func ReEnableLogin(){

    self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    self.usernameField.enabled = true
    self.passwordField.enabled = true
    self.serverNameField.enabled = true
}

func DisplayAlert(title: String, message: String){

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.ReEnableLogin()

}

func DisplayTouchIDQuestion(title: String, message: String){

    let alertControllerQuestion = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alertControllerQuestion.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(true, forKey: "useTouchID")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(true, forKey: "touchIDPreferenceSet")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(self.passwordField.text, forKey: "touchIDCachedCredential")
        self.CheckUser()
    }))
    alertControllerQuestion.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(false, forKey: "useTouchID")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(true, forKey: "touchIDPreferenceSet")
        self.CheckUser()
    }))
    self.presentViewController(alertControllerQuestion, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func CheckTouchIDCapable()-> Bool {
    var error: NSError?
    var touchEnabledDevice: Bool = false
    if authContext.canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error){
        touchEnabledDevice = true
    }
    return touchEnabledDevice
}

func TouchIDCall(){

    authContext.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: "Place your finger on the Home button to log into Collaboration User Tools", reply: { (wasSuccessful, error) in
            if wasSuccessful{
                print("\(NSDate()): Successful Biometric Authentication for user: \(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("userName")!)")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("touchIDCachedCredential"), forKey: "password")
                self.CheckUser()

            }else{
                print("\(NSDate()): Error: \(error!.code)")
                print("\(NSDate()): Unsuccessful Biometric Authentication for user: \(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("userName")!)")
                let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE
                let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
                dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, { 
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    })
                })
                self.ReEnableLogin()
            }
        })

}





}
```

I've tried:

```
NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().removeAllCachedResponses()
userSession.invalidatedAndCancel()
```

The logout table view controller calls this method:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    switch indexPath.row{
    case 0:
        myUser = User()
        myExtensions.removeAll()
        myDevices.removeAll()
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("", forKey: "password")
        userName = ""
        password = ""
        NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().removeAllCachedResponses()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("logoff", object: nil)
        performSegueWithIdentifier("logout", sender: self)
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

I don't know where the password is being cached.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please show the whole code? from the Action outlet of the button to the request.

Comment: Done.  Entire view controller is now included.  Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you call: NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue("", forKey: "password") in your logoff function?

Comment: I do.  That's the crazy part!  I have a loggout view controller that does that very thing.  I debug the code and see the null value being passed after logout but it still works. Been scratching my head for days.

Comment: Added the logout view controller to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was never related to password caching.  Most likely due to my relatively amateur experience level, I never considered the fact that it might be COOKIES keeping the session up.  That's exactly what it ended up being.  I solved the situation simply by deleting all cookies during the logout procedure.  I added the following to my logout code and it's working perfectly.

```
print("\(NSDate()): Logout Requested, Deleting Cookies")
let cookieStorage = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()
let cookies = cookieStorage.cookies! as [NSHTTPCookie]
print("\(NSDate()): Cookie count: \(cookies.count)")
for cookie in cookies{
   print("\(NSDate()): Deleting Cookie name: \(cookie.name) value: \(cookie.value)")
   NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().deleteCookie(cookie)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue lies on part of your logic when handling your password. First, in your `func CheckUser()` you assign the value of `var password` if `!logOutUser` from your user defaults, however this property (password) is not getting cleared at any point, so if `!logOutUser` is `false` (which it looks like always is, as its not getting set anywhere), and your input fields are empty, then it will use the previous value that you had store in there.

So if I am correct, and the culprit here is that the password field is storing its data, a quick, dirty fix would be to simply clear these fields (`username` and `password`) after you perform your request. A better fix would be to directly pass the `usernameField.text` value directly and clear it after its done. (I'm unsure why you are storing your user's password in your app, which I would recommend reconsidering, if you need it for validating a session you should be using authentication tokens)

```
// set up the base64-encoded credentials
let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
userPasswordString = NSString(format: "%@:%@", userName, password)
userName = ""
password = ""
```

I would also like to point out that you should be using optionals for these fields, you should be using optional unwrapping for your user defaults and also adding a validation mechanism so that you do not submit requests with empty fields, ideally your button would be disabled or you would alert your user of an invalid field.

Good Luck!

**EDIT**

Try this approach: rather than using a class property for the values of password username and server. Use method variables to set your values, this way these values will get disposed when the method terminates. (This is a bit of a shot in the dark as i dont have a compiler at hand so there might be some minor syntax errors). - **note the method signature**

```
func CheckUser(username: String, password: String, server: String){
let port = "8443"
let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let userPasswordString = NSString(format: "%@:%@", username, password)
let userPasswordData = userPasswordString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let base64EncodedCredential = userPasswordData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
let authString = "Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)"
config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders?.removeAll()
config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : authString]
config.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10.0

// create the user request
let userUrlString = NSString(format: "https://%@:%@/webserver/user/%@", server, port, username)
let userUrl = NSURL(string: userUrlString as String)
userRequest.cachePolicy = .ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
userRequest.URL = userUrl!
userRequest.HTTPMethod = "GET"
userRequest.setValue("Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
userSession = NSURLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue:NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())

//Send User Request to the server and populate labels with response.
let task = userSession.dataTaskWithRequest(userRequest) { (data, response, error) in
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

        if error?.code != nil{
            print("ERROR: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            self.DisplayAlert("Error", message: error!.localizedDescription)
        }else{
            _ = NSString (data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            let accessDenied = Bool(dataString?.rangeOfString("HTTP Status 403").location != NSNotFound)
            let authFailure = Bool(dataString?.rangeOfString("HTTP Status 401").location != NSNotFound)

            if (authFailure || accessDenied) {
                print("\(NSDate()): Unsuccessful Password Authentication Attempt for user: \(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("userName")!)")
                self.DisplayAlert("Access Denied", message: "Please Verify Your Credentials")
            }else{
                print("\(NSDate()): Successful Password Authentication for user: \(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("userName")!)")
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("authenticated", sender: self)
            }
        }
    })
}.resume()
}
```

Then you can call your method as so:

```
if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("touchIDPreferenceSet") == nil  && CheckTouchIDCapable() {
    DisplayTouchIDQuestion("Use Touch ID?", message: "Would you like to use touch ID to login?")
}else{
    usernameField.enabled = false
    passwordField.enabled = false
    serverNameField.enabled = false
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    CheckUser(usernameField.text, password: passwordField.text, server: serverNameField.text)
}
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, I have a separate menu that has the logout button.  I've added the view controller code that gets executed during logout.  I am clearing everything but it's still working.

Comment: I see, You are posting a notification to execute the logoff method, but inside this method you are not setting logOutUser. I'll update my answer with an alternate solution for your loginButton action outlet.

Comment: Thanks for the updated solution, I will check it out in the morning, about to go celebrate the 4th.  Also wanted to point out that I am setting the "logOutUser" in the prepareForSegue method right now.  I like your suggestion, I'll give it a shot and get back to you tomorrow.

Comment: Hi Daniel, unfortunately this did not work.  I'm back to the drawing board tomorrow.